# Converting ADC to voltage

Tags: adc, resolution

How can I convert the binary data to voltage: where each sample stored as 2-bytes(16-bit signed integer); and the resolution of the ADC is 14-bit with -10V to 10V range?

I tried the following which didnt work:

voltage= (20/2^14)*data - 10; (where data is a signed 16-bit integer per sample)

Comment: 1) you say ADC but what you're actually want to model is the behavior of a DAC. 2) **Think** how you want your binary data to correspond to a voltage. Example: 4 bit DAC: 0000 = -10 V and 1111 = + 10 V or use MSB as a sign: 0000 = 0 V, 0111 = 10 V, 1111 = -10 V. 3) your formula is for 14 bit yet you use 16 bit signed integers ?!?!?

Comment: The samples are saved as 16-bits(2-bytes). but the resolution is 14-bit with-10 to 10V range. what should be the correct formula here? I mean 14-bit A/D converter is used.

Comment: I'll only **help** to make you get to the right formula. I'm not going to do **your work** for you. It is not hard if you just take the time to **think** about it.

Comment: how will you do that?

Comment: Is the data right or left aligned? (It will be in the data sheet).

Comment: it is little endian

Comment: i use this to read in matlab: data = fread(fid,[1,inf],'int16','ieee-le');

Comment: Some of the bits of a 16-bit representation of a 14-bit number are not significant.  Which?  How does your 14-bit ADC represent sign?

Comment: those details are not given. here is the device: https://www.dataq.com/resources/pdfs/manuals/di710_manual.pdf

Comment: That datsheet is useless. You need two bits of information which aren't given. 1) Is the output 2's compliment or unsigned with an offset. 2) Is the data left or right aligned. You either need to ask the manufacturer this or work it out. To work it out you need the 16 bit values you get for 0V and -10V (other points would work but it's easier with two clear points like that). Not the matlab converted to an integer numbers, the raw hex values just in case matlab is messing things up (e.g. does matlab assume signed or unsigned data?)

Comment: this works: data = (20/2^16)*data; but i dont know why since 2^14 is not used anywhere

Comment: That implies that the data are left aligned to ensure that the result sets the sign bit appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the binary format the A/D produces.  Let's say it does the basic thing and produces a unsigned 14 bit value.  That means -10 V results in 0, and +10 V in 2<sup>14</sup>-1 = 16383.

Even if the A/D output is mapped differently into the 16 bit word, this is what the A/D is doing internally.  You should be able to recover the raw 14 bit value by shifting and masking, and possibly flipping a bit.

You can also put in a few known voltages and see what comes out.  The binary format should be obvious after looking at a few examples.

To reverse this process, linearly scale 0 to 16383 to map to -10 V to +10 V.

This should, of course, both be obvious and clearly spelled out in the datasheet.